# Python 2.7 & PyDev does not print all lines from files.

Tags: python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 & PyDev & Eclipse, doing print of lines from a text file, prints only the first 1500 lines out of 2200 lines. The same occurs when trying to print a 'Select' Result Set (Sqlite3).  When I run the same script under 'Idle', all lines are printed correct.
Any idea how to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Any code will do it for example:

```
    import numpy as np

    j = 0

    for i1 in np.arange(0,110,10):
        for i2 in np.arange(0,110,10):
            for i3 in np.arange(0,110,10):
                for i4 in np.arange(0,110,10):
                    j += 1
                    print i1,  i2,  i3,  i4,  j
```

print starts with line 10278 (should start at 1) and ends with line 14641
 (should end at 14641)